# Is an egalitarian inclination largely genetically determined?

Tags: politics, economics, genetics

A [2017 study](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11211-017-0297-y) titled *A Genetic Basis of Economic Egalitarianism*
seems to have concluded that:

> We use Minnesota Twin Study data from 2008, collected from samples of monozygotic and dizygotic twin pairs (n = 573) in order to estimate the additive genetic, shared environmental, and unique environmental components of social justice attitudes. Our results show that the large portion of the variance in a four-item economic egalitarianism scale can be attributed to genetic factor. At the same time, shared environment, as a socializing factor, has no significant effect.

Is this finding largely undisputed and/or corroborated by other studies? (Basically, somewhat simplifying, are would-be egalitarians simply born that way?)

Comment: It does not say would-be egalitarians simply born that way but instead that part of people's attitudes can be linked to a genetic factor and part is just random

Comment: There are several related studies they cite. Are these somehow insufficient?